# Can I keep feature extractor's weight set unchanged when fine tuning models(Transfer Learning ) with Tensorflow Object Detection API?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

There are few types of transfer learning . When using TF Object Detection API do we fine tune weights of the feature extractor when using already  [trained models on COCO Data Set](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md).

**Because sometimes we can just keep the weight set of feature extractor fix while training only the predictor layers .**

Comment: During training you can pass a `var_list` argument to the optimizer's `minimize` method (e.g. [for Adam](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/AdamOptimizer#minimize)). By default an optimizer trains all variables in the trainable variables collection, but passing an explicit list will "freeze" everything else. If that's not what you mean, you may need to provide a bit more detail in your question.

Comment: Yeah I know it. I just want to know about the tf object detection API how the do it. Because I am using their pre-trained model. So then I need to know the name scopes also .

Comment: Ah. Well, I'd dump the trainable variables ([tf.trainable_variables()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/trainable_variables)) to start, then dig through and decide which I wanted to train (i.e. ad hoc Python logic based on the variable name).

Comment: Perfect then I can have all the details . Do I need to run the inside a session ?

Comment: No session required. You'll just be examining and fiddling with the structure of the graph, not executing it. You do want to make sure that this happens after the forward pass of the graph is constructed (i.e. after the loss is defined) so that all of the trainable variables are in the graph.